# How to pass and retrieve a two dimesional Array as intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to pass a 2D array as an intent onto another activity.

This code works for sending the 2D array, the problem is retrieving it in the next activity.

```
i++;
Intent tryAgain = getIntent();
tryAgain.putExtra("index", i);
tryAgain.putExtra("from", "next");

int [][] previousValues = getSelectedIndices();
Toast.makeText(AnotherActivity.this, "Bang " + previousValues[3][3], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putSerializable("array", previousValues);

tryAgain.putExtras(mBundle);

AnotherActivity.this.finish();
startActivity(tryAgain);
```

I have already tried this code below to retrieve the 2D array, it does NOT work.

```
else if(getIntent().getStringExtra("from").equals("next")){
i=index;
int [][] arrayReceived=null;
Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("array");
if(objectArray!=null){
    arrayReceived = new int[objectArray.length][];
    for(int i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++){
       arrayReceived[i]=(int[]) objectArray[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: if you put it as `int [][] previousValues`, then why you try to retrieve it as `Object[] objectArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something for receiving array like this as an example:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int[][] list_array = (int[][])b.getSerializable("array");
```

Comment: I have tried this, the app closes down for some reason.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to int[][]

Comment: That's because you're sending an int and trying to get is as an object.

Comment: how do I fix it?

Comment: That is the same as the code that was before, but instead of b I used the getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("array");